# How to clear/acknowledge a warning in the Service Fabric Explorer

Tags: azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-on-premises

I was testing things with a non-prod cluster of On Premises Service Fabric and I stopped the process for one of my services on one of my nodes (to see how it would respond).

That caused the explorer to show the following warning:

> There was an error during CodePackage activation.The service host terminated with exit code:1

Service Fabric recovered well.  It made a new instance of the process and kept going.

But I can't seem to see how to clear out the warning from the Explorer.  In my non-prod env, I can just drop and redeploy the app.

But in prod I can't do that.  Especially not to just get rid of a warning message!

**Is there a way to tell Service Fabric, "thanks for telling me that, I know about it now and you can forget about it and carry on?"**

Comment: Im not sure about that when the cluster is normal it will clear all the warning for me. Do you have a screen shot or something please

Comment: Users are not supposed to clear up the Service Fabric System reports. Like duongthaiha mentioned, if the condition that caused the warning/error goes away, the health report should be eventually cleaned up. Either the entity on which is reported on goes away (and the report goes with it), another report is sent with state Ok to overwrite the previous one, or the report expires by itself. In your case, I believe it expires by itself after a period of time (the report TTL). If TTL is 5 minutes and RemoveWhenExpired=true, it will go away from SFX in 5 min.